# I am having some problems with array manipulation

Tags: c

I am writing some code in C in which I have to find the max element of every row and then change every element of every row left of the max element of that row to the max element of the row.

I tried this:

```
for(i=0;i<R;i++)
    {
        MAX[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<C;j++)
        {
            if(MAX[i]<A[i][j])
            {
                MAX[i]=A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<R;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<C;j++)
        {
           while(A[i][j]<MAX[i])
           {
                A[i][j]=MAX[i];
           }
        }
    }

}
```

... but of course it changes every element of every row to the max element of that row so I suspect I have to modify that block of code.
Any help would be appreciated since I am new to coding.

Comment: One option is to store the index of the max value. Then use that, instead of `C` in the second inner loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp got the answer.  When you set all the elements in the row to the max, you do it by comparing the value instead of index: `while(A[i][j]<MAX[i])`.  This will always evaluate true (or false with no change).

Comment: What should happen if the max appears 2 or more times? Ex: `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0]`

Comment: Thanks for your interest but i got my answer already

Comment: You are all wonderful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation was confusing to say the least. I think this is what you meant you wanted to achieve but I am not sure:

```
for(i=0;i<R;i++){
    MAX[i]=0;
    for(j=0;j<C;j++){
        if(MAX[i]<A[i][j]){
            MAX[i]=A[i][j];
        }
    }
}
    
for(i=0;i<R;i++){
    int j = 0;
    while(A[i][j] < MAX[i]){
        A[i][j] = MAX[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```